# How can I modify the result of a paste event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a custom textbox directive (it contains an input box inside).

```
<custom-textbox ng-paste=pasteFn($event)></custom-textbox>
```

When the user hits paste, I want to sanitize what was pasted (removes special characters + reduces the string length).

I tried looking into the event object and it looks fairly large, so I'm not sure of the best way to modify this string.

Comment: you can't. you have to allow the paste and then cleanup the target.

Comment: What would be a good way for me to do the clean up then? The pasteFn() gets called before the paste actually happens. What would be a good way for me to call something after the paste happens?

Comment: a setTimeout from before the paste should work, and should fire before the user can interact with an XSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the clipboard data and send it to your paste function like this:

```
        <input ng-paste="clean($event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))" placeholder='paste here' ng-model="paste">
pasted: {{paste}}<br>
new string: {{myString}}
```

Then in your controller:

```
    $scope.clean = function(e){
  var str = e;

 $scope.myString = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
  }
```

Here's a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/R2VP0D6Z6lJGopYGOM01?p=preview)